# сортировка строки по русскому алфавиту

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 50 //длина буфера для слова
//в русском влезет: тысячадевятьсотвосьмидесятидевятимиллиметровый
//в английском влезет: Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious

//записываем текст в файл посимвольно, попутно считаем длину
int lenOfSentence()
{  int cur = 0;
    char c;

    FILE *f = fopen("sentence.txt","w");
    if(f == NULL)
    {  printf("Scusi, temporary difficulties finding room for your sentence\n");
        getchar(); exit(1);
    }

    printf("Введите строку и нажмите ЭНТЕР :\n");
    do
    {  c = getchar();
        if(c!= '\n') fputc(c,f);  //убираем ENTER
        cur++;
    }  while (c!= '\n');
    fputc('\0',f); //добавляем символ конца строки
    fclose(f);

    return cur;   //возвращаем длину текста в файле
}

//считываем текст из файла в динамическую строку заданной длины
char *veryLongString(int len)
{  char *sentence;

    FILE *g = fopen("sentence.txt","r");
    if(g == NULL)
    {  printf("Scusi, temporary difficulties reading your sentence\n");
        getchar(); exit(1);
    }

    sentence = (char*) malloc (len);
    fgets(sentence,len,g);
    fclose(g);
    return sentence;
}

//проверка: является ли символ знаком препинания
int inDelimiters(char c)
{  int i;
    char delimiters [] = {' ','.',',','-',':',';','!','?'};
    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
        if(c == delimiters[i])
            return 1;
    return 0;
}

//укоротить текст на слово слева
char *cutSentenceByWord(char *sentence, char* word)
{  int i,cur;
    cur=strlen(word);
    while(inDelimiters(sentence[cur]))
        cur++;

    char *cut = (char*) malloc (strlen(sentence) - cur);
    for(i=cur;i<strlen(sentence);i++)
        cut[i-cur]=sentence[i];
    cut[i-cur]= '\0';

    return cut;
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main()
{  char word [N];
    int len = lenOfSentence();   //вводим текст, подсчитываем его длину
    char *sentence = veryLongString(len);  //создаем строку с текстом

    printf("\nWords:\n");  //разбираем на слова
    while(strlen(sentence)>0)
    {  sscanf(sentence,"%s",word); //считываем слово как набор символов до пробела

        if(inDelimiters(word[strlen(word)-1])) //если захватили и знак препинания справа
            word[strlen(word)-1] = '\0';    //убираем его

        printf("\t%s\n",&word[0]);
        printf("\t%g\n",word[0]);

        strcpy(sentence,cutSentenceByWord(sentence,word)); //срезаем текст на найденное слово слева
    }
    //  getchar();

    // растовляем по алфавиту
    printf("\nСлова раставленные по алфавиту:\n");  //разбираем на слова
    while(strlen(sentence)>0)
    {   sscanf(sentence,"%s",word); //считываем слово как набор символов до пробела

        if(inDelimiters(word[strlen(word)-1])) //если захватили и знак препинания справа
            word[strlen(word)-1] = '\0';    //убираем его

        char alfavit_big[] = "АБВГДЕЁЖЗИКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ";
        char alfavit_lit[] = "абвгдеёжзиклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя";

        printf("\t%s\n",word);
        strcpy(sentence,cutSentenceByWord(sentence,word)); //срезаем текст на найденное слово слева

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: не понятно, в чём именно вопрос, но, определённости ради, в рамках стандарта переносимо работать с не-LATIN-1 строками возможно только с помощью широких символов...

Comment: @Fat-Zer вообще не понял о чём ты

Comment: Без использования средств не описанных в стандарте языка Си (сторонние библиотеки, системные функции итп) полноценно работать с символьными строками, содержащими не-ASCII символы (про latin-1 я зря заикнулся), можно только с помощью широких символов (`wchar_t`). В частности на современных *nix-системах повсеместно используется utf-8, что делает виртуально невозможным индексировать символы внутри `char`-строки... и да, для сортировки строк в текущей локали достаточно `strcoll`, но для произвольной колляции без широких символов не обойтись...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле, вопрос сложнее, чем кажется. А почему именно с **русским** алфавитом работаем? Ведь если в ОС есть команда *sort* то она должна сортировать **любые** слова, по **любому** алфавиту! Так?

Интуитивно понятно, эта эта проблема может решаться по разному в разных ОС. В зависимости от используемой кодировки и наличия такого понятия как "локаль".

Хорошо, давайте посмотрим на практике. ОС Linux локаль ru.RU Кодировка UTF-8. Есть файл:

```
rows
each
Это
двумерный
массив
these
values
прозрачности
values
used
используемый
этой
демонстрации
Есть
Each
рядов
will
одного
состояния
two
Каждая
continuosly
строк
transparency
будет
постоянно
использовать
эти
значения
This
dimensional
array
this
demo
There
are
for
каждый
для
one
state
the
значений
lines
use
```

Он содержит слова, записанные вперемешку латиницей и кириллицей. Выполним сортировку:

```
$ sort test.txt 

are
array
continuosly
demo
dimensional
each
Each
for
lines
one
rows
state
the
There
these
this
This
transparency
two
use
used
values
values
will
будет
двумерный
демонстрации
для
Есть
значений
значения
использовать
используемый
Каждая
каждый
массив
одного
постоянно
прозрачности
рядов
состояния
строк
эти
Это
этой
```

Видно, что утилита *sort* со своей задачей справилась отлично. Это произошло благодаря:

> ***  WARNING  ***  The  locale specified by the environment affects
>   sort order.

Т.е. сортировка оказалась правильной благодаря тому, что утилита использует локаль. В локали прописано много чего, а в частности - порядок следования (сортировка по алфавиту) символов национальных алфавитов.

Как это достигается? Я не смотрел исходы этой утилиты, но сильно подозреваю, что в ней используется **не** функция *strcmp()*, а функция *strcoll()*, про которую читаем:

```
man 3 strcoll

Функция  strcoll()  сравнивает  строки  s1  и s2. Она возвращает целое число,
которое может быть меньше, равно или больше ноля, если выяснится, что s1
меньше, равна  или  больше  s2  соответственно.  Сравнение производится на
основе правил текущей локали, указанной в категории LC_COLLATE
```

(см. setlocale(3)).

Разумеется, это всё про Linux. В Африке всё иначе..